# The first function doesn't recognizes the new TR until I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two JS function involved in this issue which are updatePrice() and add_file(). The second function is working properly without any problem. It's just supposed to duplicate  inside . However, my problem is with the first function. It can't deal with new duplicated  until I refresh the page although back end PHP code is working properly. I hope I'm clear enough. Excuse me for maybe outdated JS code. I'm not a JS programmer, I'm a PHP developer. I found these JS codes on the internet. Here are the JS and HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.subtot, .grdtot, .grddis, .vattot, .coudis').prop('readonly', true);
            var $tblrows = $("#tblProducts tbody tr");

            $tblrows.each(function (index) {
                var $tblrow = $(this);

                function updatePrice() { // Move to separate function
                    var qty     = $tblrow.find("[data-name=qty]").val();
                    var price   = $tblrow.find("[data-name=price]").val();
                    var diss    = $tblrow.find("[data-name=discount]").val();
                    var drop_i  = $tblrow.find("[data-name=drop_i]").val();
                    
                    var coupdis = document.getElementById('coudis').value;
                    var ctype   = document.getElementById('ctype').value;
                    var cval    = document.getElementById('cval').value;
                    
                    var subTotal= parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price) - diss;

                    if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

                        $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
                        var grandTotal = {total};
                        var grandDisc  = 0;
                        
                        $(".subtot").each(function () 
                        {
                            var stval   = parseFloat($(this).val());
                            grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval  + {shipping};
                        });

                        $(".diss").each(function () 
                        {
                            var stval   = parseFloat($(this).val());
                            grandDisc += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                        });
                        
                        //$('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2) - {total});
                        
                        if(ctype == "percent")
                        {
                            var new_discount = ((grandTotal - {total}) * cval) / 100;
                        }else{
                            var new_discount = (cval);
                        }

                        var vat     = (((grandTotal - {total}) - new_discount) * 15)/100;
                        
                        $('.vattot').val(vat.toFixed(2));
                        
                        $('.grddis').val(grandDisc);
                        $('.coudis').val(new_discount);
                        
                        $('.shipping').val(shipping);
                    }
                }

                $tblrow.find('.price').on('change', updatePrice); // watch for price change
                $tblrow.find('.qty').on('change', updatePrice);   // watch for qty change
                $tblrow.find('.diss').on('change', updatePrice);   // watch for Discount change
                $tblrow.find('.sgdis').on('change', updatePrice);   // watch for Discount change
                
            });
        });
    </script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var input_field_id = null;
function add_attachs_file (file_name) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        btns = document.getElementsByName('drop');
        tr = btns[0];
        while (tr.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') tr = tr.parentNode;
        var newTr = tr.parentNode.insertBefore(tr.cloneNode(true),tr.nextSibling);
        thisChilds = newTr.getElementsByTagName('td');
        thisChilds[0].firstChild.value = file_name;
    }
}
function add_file (btn) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        tr = btn;
        while (tr.tagName != 'TR') tr = tr.parentNode;
        var idSuffix = Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
        var newTr = tr.parentNode.insertBefore(tr.cloneNode(true),tr.nextSibling);
        thisChilds = newTr.getElementsByTagName('td');
        thisChilds[0].firstChild.value = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < thisChilds.length; i++) {
            if (thisChilds[i].className == 'header') thisChilds[i].innerHTML = '';
        }
        checkForLast();
    }
}
function attachs_act (el, mode) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        tr = el;
        while (tr.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') tr = tr.parentNode;
        td = tr.getElementsByTagName('td');
        input = td[0].firstChild;
        if (mode == 1) {
            dlg = window.open('./attachs.php', 'attachs_list', 'width=400,height=600,toolbar=no,menubar=no,personalbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes');
            input_field_id = input;
        } else {
            /** delete file value */
            input.value = '';
        }
    }
}
function checkForLast() {
    btns = document.getElementsByName('drop');
    for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
        btns[i].disabled = (btns.length == 1) ? true : false;
    }
}
function drop_file(btn) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        tr = btn;
        while (tr.tagName != 'TR') tr = tr.parentNode;
        tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
        checkForLast();
    }
}
function update_attachs_value (value) {
    if (typeof input_field_id != "null") {
        input_field_id.value = value;
    }
}
function changeModel() {
  form = document.forms['frm_prop'];
    var model = form.elements['model'];
    var groupsTR = document.getElementById('groupstr');
    if (model.value == 0) {
        groupsTR.style.display = '';
    } else {
        groupsTR.style.display = 'none';
    }
  return true;
}
</script>

<table border="0" id="tblProducts" cellspacing="0" width="75%" style="direction: rtl">
        <tbody>

    <tr id="drop_item_2180.di">
        <td width="100%">
            <input type="hidden" value="2842" name="id[]">                         
            <input type="hidden" value="2180" name="row_id[]">    
            
        <div class="row py-2 text-center mb-2">
        <div class="col-1 text-center h6 m-auto font-weight-bold">1.</div>
        <div class="col-2 m-auto d-non">
            
         <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#remark_2180">
           <i class="fas fa-sticky-note text-warning fa-lg"></i>
          </a>

        <button type="button" style="cursor:pointer" value="d8a03df3" data-name="drop_i" id="drop_item_2180.di" class=" bg-white border-0"  name="drop" onClick="fetchInfo('admin.php?act=drop&t=drop_item&id=2180','live_update');drop_file(this);live_update(this);"><i class="fas fa-minus-square p-1 text-danger fa-lg mx-1"></i></button>

        <button type="button" style="cursor:pointer" id="2180.di" value="d8a03df3" class=" bg-white border-0"  name="drop" onClick="add_file(this);live_update(this)"><i class="fas fa-plus-square p-1 fa-lg text-success mx-1"></i></button>
                
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 m-auto text-center">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col p-0 text-center">
            
        <a href="../uploads/Strawberry_shortcake_new_by_rositafresita99-d634fzk.jpg" data-fancybox="images">
            <img class="rounded-circlex mx-auto" src="../uploads/Strawberry_shortcake_new_by_rositafresita99-d634fzk.jpg" style="height:30px; width:30px" />
        </a>
            
        </div>
   </div>
```

Item 1

```
            <input type="text" name="note[]" class="form-control" onfocusout="live_update(this)" id="2180.re" value=""/>

        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>

    <tr id="drop_item_2179.di">
        <td width="100%">
            <input type="hidden" value="2842" name="id[]">                         
            <input type="hidden" value="2179" name="row_id[]">    
            
        <div class="row py-2 text-center mb-2">
        <div class="col-1 text-center h6 m-auto font-weight-bold">2.</div>
        <div class="col-2 m-auto d-non">
            
         <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#remark_2179">
           <i class="fas fa-sticky-note text-warning fa-lg"></i>
          </a>

        <button type="button" style="cursor:pointer" value="d8a03df3" data-name="drop_i" id="drop_item_2179.di" class=" bg-white border-0"  name="drop" onClick="fetchInfo('admin.php?act=drop&t=drop_item&id=2179','live_update');drop_file(this);live_update(this);"><i class="fas fa-minus-square p-1 text-danger fa-lg mx-1"></i></button>

        <button type="button" style="cursor:pointer" id="2179.di" value="d8a03df3" class=" bg-white border-0"  name="drop" onClick="add_file(this);live_update(this)"><i class="fas fa-plus-square p-1 fa-lg text-success mx-1"></i></button>
                
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 m-auto text-center">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col p-0 text-center">
            
        <a href="../uploads/Strawberry_shortcake_new_by_rositafresita99-d634fzk.jpg" data-fancybox="images">
            <img class="rounded-circlex mx-auto" src="../uploads/Strawberry_shortcake_new_by_rositafresita99-d634fzk.jpg" style="height:30px; width:30px" />
        </a>
    
        </div>
   </div>
```

Duplicated Item

```
            <input type="text" name="note[]" class="form-control" onfocusout="live_update(this)" id="2179.re" value=""/>

        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the self executing function which loops on **existing** table rows , declares the `updatePrice` function, and attach it as event handler of **existing** inputs having some classes.
One solution could be using delegated event handlers instead of directly attach the events, so the program can attach event handlers for elements not yet existing, as explained here https://api.jquery.com/on/ .

But it requires a certain refactoring of the self executing function.

As second chance, less elegant but easy, you could transform the content of the self executing function in a named function and re-execute it each time you add a row.

Something like that

```
function updateAllRows(){
        --content of existing self executing js here
     }

$(function () {
     
     updateAllRows();
});
```

and then in the `add_file` function call updateAllRows

I'm sorry not being able to edit code here but i'm unable to do it in this moment. Hope it is useful

UPDATE

Today i could make the changes to your code. It should work. 4 small changes, you can see comments with //MAX.
Basically: trasformed the function called by jquery in a named function, called the function, and added the call to the same, when adding new file. See basing on comments

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //MAX ADDED NAMED FUNCT
    var listenUpdates=function () {
            $('.subtot, .grdtot, .grddis, .vattot, .coudis').prop('readonly', true);
            var $tblrows = $("#tblProducts tbody tr");

            $tblrows.each(function (index) {
                var $tblrow = $(this);

                function updatePrice() { // Move to separate function
                    var qty     = $tblrow.find("[data-name=qty]").val();
                    var price   = $tblrow.find("[data-name=price]").val();
                    var diss    = $tblrow.find("[data-name=discount]").val();
                    var drop_i  = $tblrow.find("[data-name=drop_i]").val();
                    
                    var coupdis = document.getElementById('coudis').value;
                    var ctype   = document.getElementById('ctype').value;
                    var cval    = document.getElementById('cval').value;
                    
                    var subTotal= parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price) - diss;

                    if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

                        $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
                        var grandTotal = {total};
                        var grandDisc  = 0;
                        
                        $(".subtot").each(function () 
                        {
                            var stval   = parseFloat($(this).val());
                            grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval  + {shipping};
                        });

                        $(".diss").each(function () 
                        {
                            var stval   = parseFloat($(this).val());
                            grandDisc += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                        });
                        
                        //$('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2) - {total});
                        
                        if(ctype == "percent")
                        {
                            var new_discount = ((grandTotal - {total}) * cval) / 100;
                        }else{
                            var new_discount = (cval);
                        }

                        var vat     = (((grandTotal - {total}) - new_discount) * 15)/100;
                        
                        $('.vattot').val(vat.toFixed(2));
                        
                        $('.grddis').val(grandDisc);
                        $('.coudis').val(new_discount);
                        
                        $('.shipping').val(shipping);
                    }
                }

                $tblrow.find('.price').on('change', updatePrice); // watch for price change
                $tblrow.find('.qty').on('change', updatePrice);   // watch for qty change
                $tblrow.find('.diss').on('change', updatePrice);   // watch for Discount change
                $tblrow.find('.sgdis').on('change', updatePrice);   // watch for Discount change
                
            });
        }; //MAX REMOVE CLOSED PARENTHESYS

        //MAX ADD CALL TO NEW FUNC
        $(listenUpdates);


    </script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var input_field_id = null;
function add_attachs_file (file_name) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        btns = document.getElementsByName('drop');
        tr = btns[0];
        while (tr.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') tr = tr.parentNode;
        var newTr = tr.parentNode.insertBefore(tr.cloneNode(true),tr.nextSibling);
        thisChilds = newTr.getElementsByTagName('td');
        thisChilds[0].firstChild.value = file_name;
    }
}
function add_file (btn) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        tr = btn;
        while (tr.tagName != 'TR') tr = tr.parentNode;
        var idSuffix = Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
        var newTr = tr.parentNode.insertBefore(tr.cloneNode(true),tr.nextSibling);
        thisChilds = newTr.getElementsByTagName('td');
        thisChilds[0].firstChild.value = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < thisChilds.length; i++) {
            if (thisChilds[i].className == 'header') thisChilds[i].innerHTML = '';
        }
        checkForLast();
        //MAX ADDED FUNC CALL
        listenUpdates();
    }
}
function attachs_act (el, mode) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        tr = el;
        while (tr.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') tr = tr.parentNode;
        td = tr.getElementsByTagName('td');
        input = td[0].firstChild;
        if (mode == 1) {
            dlg = window.open('./attachs.php', 'attachs_list', 'width=400,height=600,toolbar=no,menubar=no,personalbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes');
            input_field_id = input;
        } else {
            /** delete file value */
            input.value = '';
        }
    }
}
function checkForLast() {
    btns = document.getElementsByName('drop');
    for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
        btns[i].disabled = (btns.length == 1) ? true : false;
    }
}
function drop_file(btn) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        tr = btn;
        while (tr.tagName != 'TR') tr = tr.parentNode;
        tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
        checkForLast();
    }
}
function update_attachs_value (value) {
    if (typeof input_field_id != "null") {
        input_field_id.value = value;
    }
}
function changeModel() {
  form = document.forms['frm_prop'];
    var model = form.elements['model'];
    var groupsTR = document.getElementById('groupstr');
    if (model.value == 0) {
        groupsTR.style.display = '';
    } else {
        groupsTR.style.display = 'none';
    }
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're definitely right Massimo. Unfortunately, I'm zero at JS. I can't code or modify the code based on your conception. Thank you anyway

Comment: today i've a pc and i could edit the code, see my update